# Get Date and Time panel pop up where cursor is?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

This window can be dragged around just like any other window.For example, by using winmove. Before that I first have to find the window in question which is where I am stuck. AHK Spy gives me this info about it

> Date and Time Information
>
> ahk_class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow
>
> ahk_exe ShellExperienceHost.exe
>
> ahk_pid 14344

but no matter how I go about it, I get nothing. I cant get AHK to find it. Below is one of many tries, in this case, a partial title match.

```
 SetTitleMatchMode, 2

IfWinExist (Time Information)
    {
        msgbox, win found
        Return
    }


IfWinNotExist (Time Information)

    {
        msgbox, win not found
        Return
    }
```

I searched around, apparantly there are limits to IfWinExist with regards shell ShellExperience. This [fella](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=42517) found a way around but only for a start button? He didnt make it clear.

`#!d` can be used to pop up the panel. but I was hoping for something more progromatic

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see you trying to use the old syntax of **WinExist** function, but not in the correct way.

Depending on what is documented [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm), the correct syntax is like this `IfWinExist, Time Information` or like this `IfWinEXist, % "Time Information"` same with `IfWinNotExist`.

Another thing, you posted that AHK Spy gives you **Date and Time Information** as the title of that window, but you used **Time Information** instead, well if the title is wrong be sure you wont get what you want.

If you like to use the new syntax you can use it like this

`If WinExist("Time Information")` to check if the window is exist, if you want to check if it is not then you do this `If !WinExist("Time Information")`

Hope it clarify something for you.